# Microsoft Access - Does a value exist for this record?

Tags: ms-access

Forewarning - I am very new with Microsoft Access and I have limited knowledge of formulas and expressions. Go easy!

I've built a very basic database to store and track stories of people my nonprofit organization has helped (we're calling them "Subjects"). We frequently produce various publications and it's important to know when and where we've featured our subjects, so we can avoid repeating the same content in the same publication.

When we are putting together content for a new issue, we always ask ourselves "Okay, who haven't we featured in this publication before?"

**This is what I'm trying to accomplish right now:** Be able to quickly and easily find out WHO HASN'T been used in a particular publication.

Here are my tables and relationships.

[image]

A subject's content is used in any number of publications ("Use/Type Publication")

So basically, I am trying to say: **If a specific value in the "Use/Type Publication" field exists for "Subject(s)" , don't show that subject in the results**

Or alternatively, the results could just be all subjects and the return value could be a Yes/No.

I would want to be able to input the specific value.

For example, "show me all of the subjects that have never been used in our Spirit enewsletter."

I hope this is enough information. I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Assuming you are keeping an index of all of the people you have interviewed, then what you need is an index of all the names you have published before. You can then easily find the names that you have not published.  I've spent a couple years on a project that will index all names/places in publications (for WWII vets) going back to 1945 so that a master index is available for researchers.

Answer (score 0):

Design a query; when you put these 2 tables into the query design view - that join line will display assuming you've made a permanent join in relationships.  If not make a join line as you are displaying.

Then put your cursor on the line itself, right click, and alter the join type so that ALL of ContentVersion is selected.  The join line will then have an arrow pointing at Content table.

Add all the fields to the query of both tables.

Run the query and you'll get all of contentversion data and where there is no match you'll see nulls/blanks in the content.  From here you can continue to customize it to meet your needs.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Unfortunately, a ContentVersion would only be created when there is content. So there would be no blank instances for the Content.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

I created a query that took all of the publications a person had been in and concatenated them into a single cell. That way, I can just filter to exclude the publication name.

I couldn't do this in the query I was using before because the different publications a subject was in were splitting into different rows. So even if I filtered out the publication I wanted to check, the person would show up for other publications.

[Concatenated the publications into a list per subject so I could filter the subject out completely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmtik.png)

Here's a link to the function I used to accomplish it: http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html